# Multilevel lists - Document starting with second level

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I want to create a word document in MS Word 2007 with numbering starting from second level and proceeds upto fourth level. I don't want first level and second level numbering should start from 6.6.

```
6.6. Storing & Exchange of data 
     6.6.1. Storing of data to External medium
            6.6.1.1. Description 
            6.6.1.2.Inputs
     6.6.2. Importing data from external storage
            6.6.2.1. Description 
            6.6.2.2.Inputs
6.7. Filming requirements
     6.7.1. Transfer Images to Film
            6.7.1.1. Description 
            6.7.1.2.Inputs
```

Should I define a new multilevel format or can it be done by modifying existing format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to create your list:

1. With an empty document and the caret at the first position of the first line, click the "Multilevel list" button and select the third style on the first row. It looks like this:

[image]

2. Now click the same button and then "Define New Multilevel List ...".
3. Click the "More" button at the bottom of the dialog box.
4. With level 1 selected at the top left, change the value of the "Start at" field to 6.
5. Select level 2 and change the "Start at" value to 6 as well. The dialog should look like this:

[image]

6. You now have a document with a list beginning at 6. Click the "Numbering" button and then "Change List Level". Select the second option (6.6) which looks like this:

[image]

7. Adding paragraphs and changing their levels should now produce the desired structure.
8. You can save this document as a template.

Comment: Thanks. Up to this works. I started document with 6.6. When I press enter for the next point, the auto numbering shows 7.6. I want it as 6.7.